# Avro Mapreduce job failing org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro, avro4s

I am facing issue in map-reducing the avro file which has both string and array values.

```
           `Describe hdfs:/test/test.avro                                       
           number                      STRING
           totalProductFee            STRING
           productID                   STRING
           otherPartyId               STRING
           module                     STRING
           client                     STRING
           Event_DA                ARRAY
           Event_DA.recType           STRING
           Event_DA.AccountID         STRING
           Event_DA.Identifier        STRING
           Event_DA.ValueBefore       STRING
           Event_DA.ValueAfter        STRING
           Event_DA.Change            STRING
           Event_DA.ExpiryDate         STRING
```

However, when I am trying to run the job to fetch along with the array [Event_DA] of record values getting the below exceptions:

> org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Event_DA, expecting Event_DA at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:231)

It looks the issue is with the input schema file when combining both string type and array of records.

Please provide you valuable suggestion with sample schema file for these type of avro files.

Answer (score 0):

As per your schema definition, Event_DA would be a "record" type, but not "array" type.
Your Avro schema would look like this:

```
{
"type":"record",
"name":"myrecordname"
"fields": [
   {"name": "number", "type": "string"},
   {"name": "totalProductFee", "type": "string"},
   .......
   {"name": "Event_DA", "type": {"type":"record, "name":"Event_DA",
       "fields": [{"name":"recType", "type":"string"},
                  {"name":"AccountID", "type":"string"},
                  .......
                 ]
        }
   }
]}
```